# mysql union select

Tags: php, mysql

у меня социальная сеть, пишу часть добовлении личных сообшений, хочу одновременно показать и мои отправленные и принятые сообщения, проблема с select-ом

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' to_user_id = '".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC 
            UNOIN SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_user_id = '".$id."' to_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Что тут не так?

Comment: Проблема с пониманием  того что вам нужно, сейчас отличить отправленные и входящие сообщения просто невозможно.

Хотел бы добавить - не всегда 1 запрос лучше 2ух, я бы сделал 2 простых запроса и не заморачивался бы. 

Да и мне непонятно зачем выдумывать такие сложности на пустом месте?

Comment: Можно было и так написать

$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (from_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' to_user_id = '".$id."') or (from_user_id = '".$id."' to_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."') ORDER BY id DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query);
Но как написал @AlexWindHope непонятно какое сообщение куда

Comment: Можно выбрать все сообщения отправленные и принятые пользователем, собрать в массив и разбить на 2 массива отправленных и принятых, но это танцы с бубном на пустом месте

Comment: Кстати, скажи, плизз URL своей сети :)
Я просто принимаю участие в разработке одной такой известной :)))))) Хотелось бы увидеть твое творение :) Заодно поделился бы своим опытом :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "
  SELECT 
    msg.*, 
    CASE WHEN msg.from_user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS recieved
  FROM messages AS msg 
  WHERE 
    msg.from_user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
    OR msg.to_user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' 
  ORDER BY recieved, id DESC;
";
```

Поясняю: выбираем все сообщения, относящиеся к юзеру + статус (recieved, 1=входящее, 0=исходящее) и упорядочиваем сперва по "входящести", потом по id. Если нужны просто все подряд без разбиения на блоки, уберите recieved из ORDER BY.

```
$res = mysql_query($query);
while ($msg = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
  echo '<div class="msg">'.($msg->recieved ? 'Входящее' : 'Исходящее').'<br /><b>'.$msg->title.'</b><br />'.$msg->content.'</div>';
  }
```

Как-то так)

Если сообщения по двум юзерам (отправлено кому-то, получено от кого-то), блок WHERE

```
$query = " ...
  WHERE
    (msg.from_user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND msg.to_user_id='".$id."')
    OR (msg.to_user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND msg.from_user_id='".$id."')
  ...
";
```

Остальное все то же самое.

Comment: у него нет  recieved

Comment: спасибо :) просто я  ajax-ом отправляю

Comment: спасибо :) уже разобрался

Comment: И @muerto, у вас 0% принятых, так не вежливо)) (галочка слева от ответа, напомню)

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' to_user_id = '".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC 
            UNOIN SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_user_id = '".$id."' to_user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

Где б** здесь есть recieved? Кто слепой?

Comment: Я писал не про твой запрос а про его запрос, и то что у него нет поля "recieved". т.е. у него нет статуса входящее или исходящее сообщение.
 :)

Comment: @Shrek, и что из этого следует? Что я не могу так обозначить доп. поле запроса или в чем вообще смысл замечания?)

Comment: Да можешь конечно, просто в вопросе не содержится фраза, помогите со структурой БД.

В общем не бери в голову.

Comment: Да это не структура бд же x_x Не обязательно выбирать поля, я выбираю просто состояние полей и обозначаю "как поле", его нет и не должно быть в таблице (только в качестве кэша мобыть), оно присутствует только в возвращаемых значениях. Я могу так же на этой же таблице обозначить сообщения с длиной больше 200 символов, сообщения от админа, сообщения с четными и нечетными id и кучу всего еще без модификации таблиц. Этот пример будет работать на таблице ТС, не надо ничего менять.

Comment: для чего тут recieved? у меня MVC, и этот код у меня в моделе, а ajax call я направляю на action controller-а :)

Comment: Sh4dow у меня недостаточно очков

Comment: @muerto, да не может быть такого, я бы советовал админам написать. На принятие ответов ограничений нет.

А recieved нужен для сортировки и чтобы быстро отличать принятое от отправленного (т.е. просто чтобы не делать этого на php).